# rxjs/operators: can not find module

Tags: angular, typescript

I import rxjs/operators like this:

`import { map } from 'rxjs/operators';`

But that gives me the following error:

> **map** is declared but it values is never read. Cannot find module rxjs/operators

in Angular.

Please help.

Comment: What kind of version of angular & rxJs are you using?

Comment: "rxjs": "^5.0.0", @JacopoSciampi

Comment: install `npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save`

Comment: install npm install rxjs@6 rxjs-compat@6 --save . This is not working. @sachila

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using rxjs version 5.0.0 so you have to import map operator like this ::

```
import "rxjs/add/operator/map";
```

If You are using rxjs version 6.0.0 then you can import like this ::

```
 import { map } from 'rxjs/operators'
```

And if you want to use first method with rxjs version 6.0.0 then you have to install rxjs compat as mentioned in comment by @Sachilla

Comment: You actually just needs to be on 5.5.x to user the second way.

Comment: Thanks to acknowledge that I didn't know about that @Chrillewoodz